# How can I see what process has a lock on a textfile?

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I'm struggling to edit an config file for a webserver. The file is a text file, and I can open it in a text editor, but not save it. When I try to save it, it says that another application is using it, but I haven't started the webserver yet.

**Is there a way that I can see what process that has a lock on the textfile, or why I can't save the file?** I am logged in as adminstrator, and the OS is Windows Vista.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/).  It is similar to [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) which was my favorite for a long time, but LockHunter works for both 32bit and 64bit OS unlike Unlocker which only works on 32bit.

---

As of 5/7/2010, version 1.9.0, full 64-bit support has been added to Unlocker.

Comment: Thanks, LockHunter was a great tool! But the worst thing was that there was no locks on the file. So there must be another problem with my file. Maybe permissions, but I'm administrator.

Comment: The file may be corrupt too.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) for that. Just open it search for the file name. It can also close the file (right Click > close handle).

Comment: Thanks. I installed **ProcessExplorer** but when I search on "DLL or Handles" on the file, I get no results. Is there another way to search? Or maybe there is something else that is wrong.